# Hard drive failure at service provider - how to restore/remount data from/on Raid

Tags: data-recovery, raid, mdadm, software-raid

First I am not a server administrator - and am volunteering to help a non-profit with a crisis.

I start from the beginning.

The non-profit has a dedicated server contract with 1&1 internet. On which they had their website and dozens of educational DVD's which were freely accessible.

A few weeks ago the hard-drive of the dedicated server crashed and their website went down. Unfortunately they did not have proper backup in place for the contents of the site. Though they do have some database files.

When the harddrive crashed 1&1 replaced the hard drive - but left it up to the charity to restore the data from Raid.

However the server admin was no longer with the NGO and myself and another volunteer have been working to try and recover the data.
But we are completely stuck.

1&1 sent the following instructions to us [Rebuild a Software RAID Array](https://help.1and1.com/servers-c37684/dedicated-server-linux-c37687/rescue-and-recovery-c37690/rebuild-a-software-raid-array-a730894.html)
However we couldn't get this to work.
I contacted a friend who also tried but he also got stuck.

Last night I contacted 1&1 and spent an hour on the phone. They did something - which was not explained - which now means when we look at the info from the server there are more details than before.
[image: Before 1&1 made changes]
Now we have more information

```
rescue:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [faulty]
md1 : active raid1 sdb1[1] 4194240 blocks [2/1] [_U]
md3 : active raid1 sdb3[1] 482094016 blocks [2/1] [_U]
unused devices : none>

rescue:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     8390655     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         8390656    12584959     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        12584960   976773167   482094104   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x235dfe93

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048     8390655     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2         8390656    12584959     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3        12584960   976773167   482094104   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md3: 493.7 GB, 493664272384 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 120523504 cylinders, total 964188032 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md3 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 4294 MB, 4294901760 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 1048560 cylinders, total 8388480 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-usr: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders, total 8388608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-usr doesn't contain a valid partition table


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-var: 58.0 GB, 57982058496 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7049 cylinders, total 113246208 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-var doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-home: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders, total 8388608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-home doesn't contain a valid partition table
rescue:~# ^C
```

No again I need to say I don't understand what I am looking at but... there is one bit which might be interesting.

```
***Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-var: 58.0 GB, 57982058496 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7049 cylinders, total 113246208 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x00000000***
```

The size of the data 58.0GB might match the content of the crashed website etc.
Only thing is I have no idea what to do next to try and view that data

Any help greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

From `/proc/mdstat` you can see that there are two RAID1 devices configured and each of them has only one disk/partition attached. So they are still in a degraded mode.

To check if the data is still there, try to mount the LVMs listed with `lvdisplay`.
For example:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/myhome
mount /dev/mapper/vg00-home /mnt/myhome
```

If everything is as expected you now should run

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --add /dev/sda1
mdadm --manage /dev/md3 --add /dev/sda3
```

Then in `/proc/mdstat` you should see the rebuild progress described in "Step 13" of the 1&1 instructionss you posted.
Then wait for the rebuild to finish and go on with the steps described in the "GRUB Setup" in the 1&1 instructions.
After that a reboot should work as normal and there is normally no need to care about the LVM configuration if everything goes well.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Thomas
Miracles never cease it all slowly came together this afternoon.
And with your help and advice and a friend holding my hand everything slotted into place and I can access the data. At last
Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to hear the good news.